# Preview option in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, preview

In a project there is a preview option that how our website will be? For that, need to load same component twice in a component for mobile and web view, but i want whatever action done in the mobile view, the same should reflect in web view.

But currently, since i have called the same component in mobile and web view separately, if anything works in mobile view, it worked on it and not reflected the same in web view also.

So can anyone suggest a solution for this? Else is there any other way to provide preview option in angular project. If any please suggest that.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide additional info, like what your actions are doing. From the top of my head, I would suggest singleton services to exchange data between the two components.